# How do I get two arrays into iterators to go step by step?

Tags: java, list, methods, arraylist

I am still new to java and have run into this problem.

I have two arrays of data each containing numeric details.

```
    static List<String> players1 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    static List<String> players2 = new ArrayList<String>();
// Player 1 array plays player 2 array. List is always different on generation.
```

What I want to do is use both these strings in while loops to go through each of player1 array list ([4], [5] etc) strings and then get the player2 string ([0], [1] etc) then return back to the **player 1 next string value.** I had thought that the best way to do this was use iterators.

```
   Iterator it = players1.iterator();
   (it.hasNext()) {
   //get array string  
    // ++1?? 
    Iterator p2 = players2.iterator(); 
    (p2.hasNext()) {

       //get array string id.
       //return to next p1 string value.
    }
```

So  I get one id from player1 array and then loops through player2 arrays and get one id from there and it returns to the next value of player1 iterator in the while loop and gets the next id from the player2 array and so on...

My question is, is this a good way to do this? Or is there an easily method I can cycle through the arrays step by step. If you have any examples of how to make this better or using another method then that would be great.

Thanks
Java Holder.

Comment: Not sure, but I think your general concept can be improved. Why not have an Object class - Player, which has fields - id, name, etc.; Than have one collection - List<Player> ? Maybe you can just share your main problem, or give an abstract of your goal.

Comment: My goal is make player1 list play the ids of the player 2 list. However both lists are randomly generator when it runs so size and ids can be different etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Iterator<String> it1 = players1.iterator();
Iterator<String> it2 = players2.iterator();
while (it1.hasNext()&&it2.hasNext()) {
 String id1 = it1.next();
 String id2 = it2.next();
}
```

After the loops ends

- If `it1.hasNext()`, then `players2` was shorter.
- If `it2.hasNext()`, then `players1` was shorter.
- If `!it1.hasNext()&&!it2.hasNext()`, then both lists had the same size.

Comment: Yeh both lists can be different size, it depends on generation. Thanks I'll see how I can converge this.

Comment: I using this, but I have one question.  I have a method which gets the ID of the player1 called getplayer but I can't seem to reference o1 into it? I tried toString also.  
getPlayer(o1) //while looping through id's

Comment: Object o1 = it1.next();
         o1.toString();
         String id = o1.toString();
         getPlayer(id);

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your comment, but since `players1` and `players2` are generic lists, you can use `Iterator<String>`.

Comment: I just get a null pointer reference when I try and get the value of it1. 
I need to get each individual id from the player 1 and player 2 iterators on each loop through..
getId(player1ids);

getId(player2ids);

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use iterators here. Instead, use an [enhanced `for` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) like this:

```
for (String player1 : players1) {
    for (String player2 : players2) {
        System.out.println("player1 is: " + player1 + ", player2 is: " + player2);
    }
}
```